# SQL Update, updates all rows (MS-SQL 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

**Problem:** (Please see build script below, Stations belong to Satellites, Satellites belong to groups)

I am trying to update the Station table's hardware descriptor when a group number is changed on a group to which the station belongs. Ultimately, this will become a trigger. However, my update statements are affecting all rows of the station table, and I just don't see why.

Both Try#1 and Try#2 below update every row in the stations table, not just rows that belong to group (Id = 2).

*(ps. please pardon the naming conventions, this is a DB that I inherited)*

**Try #1:**

```
DECLARE  @insertedID BIGINT = 2

UPDATE STA SET
HardwareDescriptor  = CONVERT(nvarchar(10),G.GroupNum) + '-'
                    + CONVERT(nvarchar(10),SAT.SatelliteNum) +  '-'
                    + CONVERT(nvarchar(10),STA.StationNum)

FROM Station STA
    INNER JOIN Satellite SAT ON STA.SatelliteID = SAT.SatelliteID
    INNER JOIN [Groups] G ON SAT.GroupID = SAT.GroupID      

WHERE G.GroupId = @insertedID
```

**Try #2:**

```
DECLARE  @insertedID BIGINT

SET @insertedID = 2

UPDATE Station SET
HardwareDescriptor  = CONVERT(nvarchar(10),STA.GroupNum) + '-'
                    + CONVERT(nvarchar(10),STA.SatelliteNum) +  '-'
                    + CONVERT(nvarchar(10),STA.StationNum)

FROM (SELECT STA.StationId, SAT.SatelliteID, G.GroupId,
             STA.StationNum, SAT.SatelliteNum, G.GroupNum
             FROM Station STA
                INNER JOIN Satellite SAT ON STA.SatelliteID = SAT.SatelliteID
                INNER JOIN [Groups] G ON SAT.GroupID = SAT.GroupID
                AND G.GroupId = @insertedID) STA

WHERE STA.StationId = Station.StationId
```

**BUILD SCRIPT:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Station') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE Station;
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('Satellite') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE Satellite;
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('Groups') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE Groups;
GO
CREATE TABLE Groups
(
GroupId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
GroupNum INT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE Satellite
(
SatelliteId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
SatelliteNum INT NOT NULL,
GroupId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Groups(GroupId)
);

CREATE TABLE Station
(
StationId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
HardwareDescriptor NVARCHAR(20),
StationNum INT NOT NULL,
SatelliteId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Satellite(SatelliteId)
);
INSERT INTO Groups (GroupId, GroupNum) VALUES 
(1, 1), (2, 2), (3,3)
INSERT INTO Satellite (SatelliteId, SatelliteNum, GroupId) VALUES
(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 1), (3, 3, 2), (4, 4, 2);
INSERT INTO Station (StationId, SatelliteId, StationNum) VALUES
(1, 1,1 ), (2, 1, 2), (3,1, 3), (4, 2, 4), (5,2, 5), (6, 3, 6), (7,3, 7),      (8,3, 8), (9,3, 9);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first try this line:

```
INNER JOIN [Groups] G ON SAT.GroupID = SAT.GroupID
```

should be

```
INNER JOIN [Groups] G ON SAT.GroupID = G.GroupID
```

I would think that correcting this join should solve the problem. The second try suffer from the same problem in the query used as the source derived table.

Comment: Wow do I feel like an idiot! I can't tell you how many times I passed over that. Thank you for the fresh set of eyes.

Comment: Sometimes a fresh set of eyes is all we need :)